# Solve Word Search Automatically (4x4)

Tags: python, cpu-word, solver

I try to make a word search solver, I'm not a programmer but I use python to automate small tasks in my day to day :) In this occasion I want to surprise my grandmother by showing her that a computer can solve her newspaper word search automatically, this is 4x4 and can be moved in any direction to nearby cells (not only diagonal, vertical and horizontal, if the cell is close is valid) This is the code I've made

So far I have managed to find the words that match the letters, but I do not know how to teach you to take only the one that has nearby cells, I would really appreciate your help

note: the file "twl06.txt" is simply a dictionary with words.

Update: With nearby cells, I mean that words are not formed in simple straight lines, since they are valid while the cell is next to it

[image]

```
#For example: niosijmcyhtedfio

palabra2=input("Insertar letras: ")
print ("")
print ("")
f=open("twl06.txt")
libro=f.read()

print ((palabra2[0]), (""),(palabra2[1]), (""),(palabra2[2]), (""),(palabra2[3]))
print ((palabra2[4]), (""),(palabra2[5]), (""),(palabra2[6]), (""),(palabra2[7]))
print ((palabra2[8]), (""),(palabra2[9]), (""),(palabra2[10]), (""),(palabra2[11]))
print ((palabra2[12]), (""),(palabra2[13]), (""),(palabra2[14]), (""),(palabra2[15]))
print ("")
print ("")

#palabra2 es con repeticiones
#palabra es sin repeticiones
palabra = ("".join(set(palabra2)))

comparacion = []       


with open("twl06.txt") as f:

    for line in f:
        lista1 = (list(palabra))
        lista2 = (list(line.rstrip('\n')))

        comparacion = []

        for item in lista1:
          if item in lista2:
            comparacion.append(item)

        if len(comparacion) == 3:

            if (len(lista2)) == 3:

                  print (" ".join(str(x) for x in lista2))
                  comparacion = []

        if len(comparacion) == 4:

            if (len(lista2)) == 4:

                  print (" ".join(str(x) for x in lista2))
                  comparacion = []

        if len(comparacion) == 5:

            if (len(lista2)) == 5:

                  print (" ".join(str(x) for x in lista2))
                  comparacion = []

        if len(comparacion) == 6:

            if (len(lista2)) == 6:

                  print (" ".join(str(x) for x in lista2))
                  comparacion = []

        if len(comparacion) == 7:

            if (len(lista2)) == 7:

                  print (" ".join(str(x) for x in lista2))
                  comparacion = []

f.close()
```

Comment: "I do not know how to teach you to take only the one that has nearby cells" << could you please update your question to include an example of what this means exactly?

Comment: I uploaded an example image, maybe that way I could explain better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your field as an array of arrays 
(Correct formating sacrificed for illustrative purposes):

```
field= [
  [ 
    [entry1],[entry2],[entry3]
  ],[
    [entry4],[entry5],[entry6]
  ],[
    [entry7],[entry8],[entry9]
  ]
]
```

Your field will be organized like this:

```
[0][0] | [0][1] | [0][2]
------------------------
[1][0] | [1][1] | [2][2]
------------------------
[2][0] | [2][1] | [2][2]
```

so the cells adjacent to `field[m][n]` can be iterated by

```
i = m-1
while i < m+1 :
  j=n-1
  while j < n+1:
    if (i = m && j = n):
      continue #skip the cell itself
    doSomething(field[i][j])
    j = j+1
  i = i+1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help friend, although I tried to implement the code I received several errors ... I finally chose to make a modular system, it took me one day but it works. I would publish it in case someone needs it in the future, but since I am not a programmer it took me 8,000 lines and is so poorly optimized that I do not think it will help anyone u.u

Comment: My python is a bit rusty, but I'm glad that the idea got across. I hope your grandma enjoys the surprise gift!